# using Django crispy forms, how do you shrink the text box for a TextField?

Tags: django, resize, textfield, django-crispy-forms

The text boxes that crispy forms lay out for TextField columns are too tall for my app, they are taking up too much screen space.  The user can make them taller if desired by dragging the bottom frame line, but the minimum size is too tall.  I would like the default height to be 4 rows or so.

I tried some ideas I got off related posts, but nothing  worked -- the text boxes were still the same height and too tall.

Here is the model I am working on at the moment:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    cTitle          = models.CharField(
                        'brand name', max_length = 48, db_index = True)
    bWanted         = models.BooleanField(
                        'want anything from this brand?', default = True )
    bAllOfInterest  = models.BooleanField(
                        'want everything from this brand?', default = True )
    cLookFor        = models.TextField(
                        'Considered a hit if this text is found '
                        '(each line evaluated separately, '
                        'put different look for tests on different lines)',
                        null=True, blank = True )
    iStars          = IntegerRangeField(
                        'desireability, 10 star brand is most desireable',
                        min_value = 0, max_value = 10, default = 5 )
    cComment        = models.TextField( 'comments', null = True, blank = True )
    cNationality    = CountryField( "nationality", null = True )
    cExcludeIf      = models.TextField(
                        'Not a hit if this text is found '
                        '(each line evaluated separately, '
                        'put different exclude tests on different lines)',
                        null=True, blank = True )
    iLegacyKey      = models.PositiveIntegerField('legacy key', null = True )
    tLegacyCreate   = models.DateTimeField( 'legacy row created on',
                        null=True, blank = True )
    tLegacyModify   = models.DateTimeField( 'legacy row updated on',
                        null=True, blank = True )
    iUser           = models.ForeignKey( User, verbose_name = 'Owner',
                        on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    tCreate         = models.DateTimeField( 'created on', auto_now_add= True )
    tModify         = models.DateTimeField( 'updated on', auto_now    = True )
    #

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cTitle

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = 'brands'
        ordering            = ('cTitle',)
        db_table            = verbose_name_plural
```

But only these fields are on the form:

```
tModelFields = (
    'cTitle',
    'bWanted',
    'bAllOfInterest',
    'cLookFor',
    'iStars',
    'cComment',
    'cNationality',
    'cExcludeIf' )
```

Guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share me what you have given in your `models.py` for that field

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `crispy_forms` according to their documentation you could use `Layouts` to define some attributes of the field's "element" that will be added to the template, [as it is explained here in the documentation](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#layout-objects-attributes).

In this case it would be something like this: `Field('cExcludeIf', rows='4')`

Comment: I appreciate the input.  I tried it.  I set Field('cExcludeIf', rows='2'), but the text box on the page is still 10 lines high.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cExcludeIf      = models.TextField(
                    'Not a hit if this text is found '
                    '(each line evaluated separately, '
                    'put different exclude tests on different lines)',
                    null=True, blank = True )
```

to

```
cExcludeIf      = models.forms.CharField(
                    'Not a hit if this text is found '
                    '(each line evaluated separately, '
                    'put different exclude tests on different lines)',
                    null=True, blank = True,
                    widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={
                                        'rows': 2})) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do initialize your form using the standard `__init__` then do as follows:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     # do what ever you need to initialize your form

     # Then, for any TextField set rows like so:
     self.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs = {'rows': 4}
```

Comment: This seems too much like a question. Please rephrase into an explained conditional answer: "If the problem is ... then the solution is ... because ...".

Comment: I’ll respectfully disagree. I don’t want to assume this user is initializing their form the same way I generally do. My answer clearly follows the if-then conditional you’re referring to after my first statement/question for clarification. Appreciate your feedback though.

Comment: With the "if" you do not assume. Without the "?" you avoid the impression of misusing an answer for a question and getting your post flagged as something which a comment should be used for. Misusing an answer for that is not appreciated and risking that impression is .. risky. Feel free to undo my edit, but I think it is in your interest. And you might consider getting closer to [answer] by describing the effect of what you propose and why it helps to solve the problem described at the top of this page.

Comment: The edit doesn't bother me. No big deal in my book. Appreciate the feedback.